# Найти определенное слово в треугольных скобках с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть текст:

```
text = 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqq >hello world< qqqqqqqqqqqqqq >houses and apartments< qqqqqqqqqq >hello kitty< qqqqqqqqqqqq'
```

Из которого мне нужно узнать где конкретно в тексте (получить индекс) выражения в треугольных скобках. Сложность заключается в том что мне нужно определенное выражения в треугольных скобках, с определенными словами, а именно: houses and apartments.
При этом порядок эти слов может меняться местами: apartments and houses.

Что бы получить текст в треугольных скобках я делал так:

```
match = re.search(r"\>([a-z ]+)\<", text)
```

или так:

```
match = re.search(r'>(.*?)<', text)
```

И в первом и во втором случае я находил 'hello world'.
Вот в чем вопрос, как мне найти текст в треугольных скобках с определенными словами (houses, and, apartments)?

Comment: Если использовать find то получится целый список разных вариантов:
text.find('houses and apartments')
text.find('houses apartments')
text.find( apartments and 'houses')
text.find( apartments  'houses')
 и тд 
Так как порядок слов для поиска может меняться.

Я хотел узнать можно ли это как то обыграть при помощи регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте, например, метод `re.finditer()`

```
import re

text = 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqq >hello world< qqqqqqqqqqqqqq >houses and apartments< qqqqqqqqqq >hello kitty< qqqqqqq>apartments houses and <qqqqq'

for m in re.finditer(r'(?<=>)[^<>]*(?:houses|and|apartments)[^<>]*(?=<)', text):
    print(f'`{m[0]}` начинается с {m.span()[0]} символа')
```

```
`houses and apartments` начинается с 45 символа
`apartments houses and ` начинается с 101 символа
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно и без регулярок.

```
text = 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqq >hello world< qqqqqqqqqqqqqq >houses and apartments< qqqqqqqqqq >hello kitty< qqqqqqqqqqqq'
result = []
lst_first = [i for i, j in enumerate(text) if j == '>']
for i in lst_first:
    for j in range(i, len(text)):
        if text[j] == '<':
            result.append(text[i+1:j])
            break
print(result)
#['hello world', 'houses and apartments', 'hello kitty']
```